# Is it possible to use a Cleric's Melee power with a Non-Melee weapon?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, cleric, ranged-attack

So I'm still pretty new to 4e and I had a concept for a primarily "spellcaster" Human Cleric that uses a bow instead of a regular melee weapon. (A close comparison is Kikyo/Kagomae from Inuyasha.) Basically what I'm looking for is either a way to utilize a ranged instead of a melee weapon to execute powers such as "Righteous Brand" or "Healing Strike" that have a melee keyword. If that's impossible, then I'd like to look for a way to either (bless/enchant/use a ritual) to put the spell on my arrows OR find poisons/enchantments with similar effects. Either solution solves my problem.

My cleric also carries a dagger and isn't *that* squishy, but I'd still prefer her to stay out of the main fight if possible. I have access to most of the books but I would need help finding enchanted arrows, rituals, or poisons.

---

P.S. And forgive me but no, I wouldn't want to play another class because that would require learning a new class in the middle of our campaign.

Comment: Related question at [Are there recommendations or pitfalls for playing an archer cleric?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/8153)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Without homebrew, your choices are *very* limited.

The **Seldarine Dedicate** paragon path from Divine Power allows you to use a bow as an implement for cleric & Seldarine Dedicate powers. You must be an elf or eldadrin to take this PP.

The **Arrow of the Moonbow** paragon path from Dragon 386 offers a similar feature. It's not *quite* as good as Seldarine Dedicate, but I believe the only prereq is that you worship Sehanine.

The **Moonbow Dedicate** feat, also from Dragon 386, lets you use the shortbow only (no longbow or greatbow) as an implement for arcane & divine powers, as well as acting as an expertise feat for the shortbow (both weapon & implement). Again, Sehanine-worshippers only.

As far as using a ranged weapon for cleric *weapon* attacks goes, I don't think there's *any* way to do that. Classes in 4e weren't designed to fill all possible niches, and bard & warlord got almost all of the "healer with a bow" support.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Oblivious Sage's comments, I came up with a solution: For my character I decided to spec her so that her bow is fairly comparable in damage to her class powers. In addition, I'm working with the DM to get poisons and enchantments that I can to apply to her ammunition. That way she still gets her arrows that have *similar* effects to the powers I wanted to replicate. Also beefed up her Con a bit just in case I want her to get a little closer.

No real headway yet about transferring spells to arrows, but I like her build as it is now. Also heard a rumor about some reinforced elven bow that can be used as both a bow and a staff, so I'll look into that to save trouble with melee combat.

Comment: Answer posts aren't direct replies (and aren't even guaranteed to be shown in chronological order), so it's not useful/appropriate to address an answer to another answer; instead, answers should always be addressed to the *question*. It's OK, but not really necessary, to give credit for someone who inspired a solution that you actually did the work to create; if one wanted to however, the latest edit is how it would be done, so that it is an answer addressing the question, rather than a reply in a “discussion” (which is not what these Q&A posts are).

Answer (score 1):

**A melee power can only be executed with a melee attack**

First, regarding the bow/staff.  If it does exist, then it would exist to allow you too shoot from range but also whack them upside the head as a staff/ use it as an implement since it is a staff.  implements and melee attacks are not the same thing.  Basically, what the bow would let you do is focus your magic through the bow rather than having to equip your holy focus to get the implement bonus.

Melee powers have to be carried out within one square.  On your other abilities you see things such as ranged 10 or close burst 5.  If you aren't sure what those mean, check out the Player's Handbook.

I know you don't want to learn a new class, but have you considered Hybrid or Multiclassing?  This way, you don't learn a new class, just a few points/powers of that class

Here's what you do:

Take your non-melee powers for a cleric, then take a multiclass bard/warlord feat to take some more ranged abilities so you aren't stuck with melee powers you cant use.  Hybrid works even better, but unless you DM allows you to recon it, you'd have to remake the character.  Multiclassing, however will allow you to keep playing the same character while slowly adding more ranged skills, and opening up ranged support Paragon Paths.

There's your ranged Cleric!